# c++ lambda can't convert to int

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, visual-studio-2013

I attempting to use a nested lambda as follows:

```
int main() {
    auto x=[](int a){
        return [a](int b){
            return a+b;
        };
    };

    int xx = x(1)(2);
    
    (void)xx;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the vs2013 compiler yields an error (C++11 language level):

> [...] can't convert to int.

What is wrong?

Comment: Your example is well-formed; likely a bug in the, by now, quite old MSVC compiler version used in VS2013.

Comment: Don't tag spam. This has absolutely nothing to do with C.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code. It's a bug in your compiler.

Comment: Just to add to dfri and samvarshavchik's responses. MSVC 12.0 (Visual Studio 2013) doesn't claim to be a compliant C++11 compiler, its support for c++11 features should be considered experimental. If you can, move to a newer compiler and I expect this will work. For example on Visual Studio 2017 this is valid: https://godbolt.org/z/fhK1KK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet is well-formed, and this is a compiler limitation or bug in the MSVC C++ compiler version used in VS2013. Note that VS2013 only claimed partial C++11 support, as per e.g. [*What's New for Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh409293(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> #### Improved ISO C/C++ Standards Support
>
> #### Compiler
>
> **Supports these ISO C++11 language features:**
>
> - [...]